# Overridding a function that has a special type (a class) as a parameter ?

Tags: ios, swift

*First, I'd like to mention, that I'm a swift beginner, and this is my first programming experience ever. So the questions may sounds super obvious to some of you... Thanks you for your understanding :)*

There's something I don't understand when accessing a superclass function with the subclass overrided function of the same name.

This is involving a "special type" as mentionned in the tuto I'm currently following :

> "The play(_:) method returns a String to be played. **You might wonder
>   why you would bother creating a special Music type**, instead of just
>   passing along a String array of notes. This provides several
>   advantages: Creating Music helps build a vocabulary, enables the
>   compiler to check your work, and creates a place for future
>   expansion."

https://www.raywenderlich.com/160728/object-oriented-programming-swift

Considering the following code :

```
class Music {

    let notes: [String]

    init(notes: [String]) {
        self.notes = notes
    }

    func prepared() -> String {
        return notes.joined(separator: " ")
    }

}

class Instrument {

    let model: String

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model

    }

    func play(_ music: Music) -> String {
        return music.prepared()
    }

}

class Piano: Instrument {

    let hasPedals: Bool

    init(hasPedals: Bool, model: String) {
        self.hasPedals = hasPedals
        super.init(model: model)

    }

    override func play(_ music: Music) -> String {
        let preparedNotes = super.play(music)
        return "Piano playing \(preparedNotes)"

    }

}
```

What I understand is :

- 1) The `class Music` allows me to create a String of note.
- 2) This requires an input (using the initializer) that will be an Array
- 3) This input is then converted with .joined(separator: " ") to a String
- 4) The class Instrument has a `func play(_ music: Music)` that accept the class Music as an input. The parameter name is music:
- 5) The parameter Music can be set by creating an instance of the Music class (as mentioned in point 2)
- 6) The `class Piano: Instrument` has an `override func play(_ music: Music)`
- 7) By adding `let preparedNotes = super.play(music)` we are accessing the parent class `func play(_ music: Music)` (just for the fun of it, because it don't seems to me that we add any changes right ?)

*- **First question** : as it seems to be possible to use a class as parameter for a function, can anyone shows me any documentation related to this topic ? I've searched into the Apple documentation without being able to find anything about that... And this is really confusing me.*

*- **Second question** : can someone please explain to me, why we are using (music) after super.play ? When I use auto-complete, the proposition is `super.play(music: Music)` and this is super confusing. It's like we are using the parameter name as a valide parameter here. Is this because, we intend to set the Music parameter first by creating an instance of Music ?-*

*- **Third question** : why are we talking about "special type" in the quote ? And what is a special type anyway ?*

Thank you very much for reading all of this !

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158

Comment: Thank  you, but I can't find anything related to any "special type" into this documentation. I've took a serious look into it before asking my question here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first:** You can find docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158

**second:** You pass object which calls `musi`c into `play` method of superclass. Even if you `override` the method `M` in inherited class, you can access original implementation of method `M` in superclass.

**Third question:** Why did their pass object of type `Music` insted of `[String]`? This is OOP, you create classes for entities which want represent into program. Also, as you can see, class `Music` contains method `prepared`, which doesn't include `Array` type. And I think you will add some new helpful methods into `Music` class in the future.

Do not hesitate to ask questions.